# How to configure DaemonSet Fluentd to read from custom log file and console

Tags: kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I'm trying to configure EFK stack in my local minikube setup. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.metricfire.com/blog/logging-for-kubernetes-fluentd-and-elasticsearch/).

Everything is working fine (I can see all my console logs in kibana and Elasticsearch). But I have another requirement. I have Node.js application which is logs as files to custom path `/var/log/services/dev` inside the pod.

File Tree:

```
/var/log/services/dev/# ls -l
total 36
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         28196 Nov 27 18:09 carts-service-dev.log.2021-11-27T18.1
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          4483 Nov 27 18:09 carts-service-dev.log.2021-11-27T18
```

How to configure my Fluentd to read all my console logs and also read logs from the custom path configured?

My App Deployment File:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: carts
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: carts
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: carts
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: carts-service
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
```

My Fluentd DaemonSet File:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
        - name: varlog
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      tolerations:
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
        - name: fluentd
          image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-elasticsearch
          volumeMounts:
            - name: varlog
              mountPath: /var/log
            - name: varlibdockercontainers
              mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
              readOnly: true
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          env:
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
              value: "elasticsearch.default"
            - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
              value: "9200"
```

I do know that log files written into custom path `/var/log/services/dev` will be deleted if pod crashes. So I have to use persistent volume to mount this path.

But I lack the experience of how to create persistent volume for that path and also link Fluentd to read from it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a pod crashes, all logs still will be accessible in `efk`. No need to add a persistent volume to the pod with your application only for storing log file.

Main question is how to get logs from this file. There are **two main approaches** which are suggested and based on kubernetes documentation:

1. **Use a sidecar container**.

   Containers in pod have the same file system and `sidecar` container will be streaming logs from file to `stdout` and/or `stderr` (depends on implementation) and after logs will be picked up by kubelet.

   Please find [streaming sidecar container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container) and example how it works.
2. **Use a sidecar container with a logging agent**.

   Please find [Sidecar container with a logging agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-logging-agent) and configuration example using `fluentd`. In this case logs will be collected by `fluentd` and they won't be available by `kubectl logs` commands since `kubelet` is not responsible for these logs.

Comment: Thank you @moonkotte. If i run as Sidecar container i should not run fluentd as DaemonSet right ? Anyone of the approach i have to take, not both. Correct me if i wrong.

Comment: Also i know it wrong to ask. But can you upvote the question, so i want to see how as community everyone dealing with it. Different solutions may be. Thanks

Comment: @Sathish You don't need to change anything related to `fluentd` itself - if you closely look into manifest, there are volume mounts using `hostPath` which means `fluentd` gets logs from each host where it's run (since pods can be run on all nodes, it has to be a `daemonset`). Then it depends on requirements and approach. For instance in the 1st approach, sidecar container will stream logs from file to `stdout` which will be collected by `fluentd` in `/var/lib/docker/containers`. In the 2nd one `fluentd` will read logs from file and stream them to its storage directly.

Comment: @Sathish As for the second part, this is a recommended approach for kubernetes, so there are not that many different options regarding architecture and concepts.